# script to switch to fullscreen app space

Tags: script, spaces, fullscreen

I would like a script to manage the switch between spaces. I don't want to switch to a specific desktop, but to a fullscreened app (i.e : iTunes). 
I already tried the `activate` command in script editor, but it only switches the menubar, not the app interface.

I don't know if it matters, but I disabled auto rearrange spaces based on the most recent used.

Comment: this is my post and I got asked to clarify it and repost it, which I did.

Comment: Victor, please edit your original post with additional information, don‘t post a new question